# Finding tab and/or space separated words in a string (dependencies in a target in a makefile)

Tags: c, data-structures, makefile, text-files

I'd like to write a program in C, which takes a line in a makefile, and process it in a few ways:

1. If the line contains a colon, we assume that it is a target line, and that there exists a target name before the colon.
2. On target lines, we store the target in a variable *targetName* as a null-terminated string.
3. On target lines, we then look for any dependencies in the same line as the target, after the colon. Zero or more whitespace characters (spaces and tabs) may appear after the colon, between dependancies or at the end of the line, but we are only interested in strings which either:
   a. Identify existing files on disk,
   b. Identify other targets, or
   c. Identify a web-based URL.

A line to be processed from a makefile could look something like this:

```
calcmarks.o : calcmarks.c calcmarks.h    globals.o
```

Where `calcmarks.o` is the name of the target, and `calcmarks.c` , `calcmarks.h` and `globals.o` are all names of dependencies, with the first 2 being files on disk and the final dependancy being another target. We would store `calcmarks.o` in the variable *targetName* , and then select a suitable data structure to store the other dependencies. I would like to store the names of the dependencies in such a way which makes it easy for me to later check the modification date of any dependency and compare it with the modification date of the target to see if the dependency has been modified more recently than the target.

Here is the code which I've been able to come up with so far. Essentially this function takes the file pointer and the target to be rebuilt, and will eventually rebuild it.

```
// filePtr is the text file pointer after going through processVariables
// Target is the name of the target isolated from the command line interface (requested by user)
void processTarget (FILE* filePtr , char target[]) {
    // Holds line by line
    char buffer[1000];

    // Holds name of target with no whitespace
    char targetName[1000];

    // Boolean to check if the target was indeed found
    bool targetFound = false;

    while (fgets(buffer , sizeof(buffer) , filePtr) != NULL) {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; buffer[i] != '\0'; i++) {
            // Copying a potential target name until we find a colon
            if (buffer[i] == ':') {
                // Don't copy the colon, so terminate the string
                targetName[i] = '\0';
                targetFound = true;
                break;
            }
            targetName[i] = buffer[i];
        }
        // If the previous loop encountered a target name via the existance of a semicolon
        if (targetFound) {
            // If the target name is the same as the required target
            if (target == targetName) {
                // Test for 0 dependencies
                if (buffer[i + 1] == '\0') continue; // End of string

                int j;
                for (j = i + 1; j != '\0'; j++) {
                    // Processing the line after the colon
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also note that the number of dependencies is variable; thus if I were to initialise a construct to store their names, I wouldn't know the size parameter.

**How do I search for dependencies after the colon, ignoring whitespace, and storing the names of dependencies in a data structure?**

---

**EDIT:** A clarification thanks to @JonathanLeffler: The dependencies which this project has to recognise will not be much harder than those shown in the line provided below, with the exception of web-based URLs.

Comment: You can use `strchr()` to find characters such as a colon `:` more directly than writing the loop yourself.  You've not shown the data structure you want to populate.  You've not shown code that copies the string into newly allocated memory.  You've not created an MCVE ([MCVE]).  Space separated words can be isolated using judicious combinations of `strspn()` and `strcspn()`.  Eventually, you'll need to work with macro expansions and other more complex notations than the example line you show, but those can wait for later.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler It would be a good time to note that for the purposes of this project, I will not have to deal with notation that is too much more complex than the line shown; the only type of dependency I haven't provided an example for is the URL type. There is no application for an MCVE (I am familiar with it) in this question as I am not showing a problem with the code I already have; rather, I have reached a roadblock in my progress and am unsure as to how to write the next part of my code. I am unable to show the data structure as I am unsure what kind of data structure I should use.